# Laravel 5.4 Modules: NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-routing

Yep, it's another Laravel route not found issue! This is actually quite an odd one. I am aware there are multiple issues here with the same error message at least, but none that seem to be the same as mine.

I am using the nWidart/laravel-modules (https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules) package for Laravel to create a module-based setup. I began with a fresh install of Laravel 5.4 via Composer, then generated the basic user authentication via `php artisan make:auth`. After basic setup, my `app/Http/routes.php` file looks like this:

```
// home page
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

// login, logout, register, etc.
Route::auth();

// admin dashboard
Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index');
```

I then installed the modules package via Composer and ran `php artisan module:make Finances Jobs Etsy` to create three modules, Finances, Jobs, and Etsy. This ran without incident. I then went into the `Http/routes.php` file for each individual module and added the `auth` middleware and an additional prefix to each route group:

```
// Finances routes file
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth'], 'prefix' => 'admin/finances', 'namespace' => 'Modules\Finances\Http\Controllers'], function()
{
    Route::get('/', 'FinancesController@index');
});

// Jobs routes file
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth'], 'prefix' => 'admin/jobs', 'namespace' => 'Modules\Jobs\Http\Controllers'], function()
{
    Route::get('/', 'JobsController@index');
});

// Etsy routes file
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth'], 'prefix' => 'admin/etsy', 'namespace' => 'Modules\Etsy\Http\Controllers'], function()
{
    Route::get('/', 'EtsyController@index');
});
```

Now here is the very frustrating issue: all the base app routes work fine. The home page route, the auth routes, and the `/admin` route all work perfectly. In addition, all the `Jobs` module routes work perfectly as well. *However*, any and all routes from the `Finances` and `Etsy` modules do *not* work. Trying to access `https://[site url]/admin/finances` shows me the following error:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

Which to me says, Laravel can't find the given route, despite being able to find the route for the Jobs module.

*Extra* confusingly, it sort of seems like Laravel *can* find the routes, as running `php artisan route:list` DOES show me the routes for the Finances and Etsy modules.

I have also tried running `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan route:clear` multiple times, in case it was some sort of caching issue. No luck.

So at this point I have absolutely no idea what to make of all this. I've got three modules, one whose routes are working perfectly, and two others, whose identically-configured routes are not working at all, yet *are* being found by `route:list`. I'm pretty much out of ideas as to what the issue could be at this point.

UPDATE: interestingly, if I place the route in the base app `routes.php` file like so:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth'], 'prefix' => 'admin/finances'], function()
{
    Route::get('/', '\Modules\Finances\Http\Controllers\FinancesController@index');
});
```

Then the route *does* work. So it seems to be an issue where the web application specifically can't seem to find the `routes.php` files for those two modules, but the console application can.

Comment: Tried `composer dump-autoload` ?

Comment: I have now - still no luck unfortunately.

Comment: I'm not sure if the module is enabled by default, but you could try `php artisan module:enable Finances`

Comment: `Module [Finances] has already enabled.` is unfortunately the message I get.

Comment: As per their github page *By default the module classes are not loaded automatically* So in your `composer.json` have you made an entry `"Modules\\": "Modules/"` under psr-4 autoloading?

Comment: Yes I have - and of course, one of the modules IS actually working as well. I've also checked each module's individual composer.json and module.json and they all seem to be correct.

Comment: did you find the solution? i am facing a similar issue with the Auth for module routes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50962453

Answer (score 0):

I has the same issue, I solved it adding name property in:

Module/[ModuleName]/Http/routes.php,

For example:

Route::get('alias','controller@functionName')**->name('module.alias')**;

I hope this tip could help you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and it solved like this.
Change file modules.php :

```
'scan' => [
    'enabled' => false,
    'paths' => [
        base_path('vendor/*/*'),
    ],
],
```

To this:

```
'scan' => [
    'enabled' => true,
    'paths' => [
        base_path('modules/*'),
    ],
],
```

And then run:

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan optimize
```