# Auth::user() returns null on Module __construct()

Tags: laravel, laravel-authentication

I created a new Module named `Article` using [laravel-modules](https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules). Some backend routes needed authentication and i added `auth` middleware and an additional permission `view_backend`. I am using https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission package for role-permissions.

the issue is when i try to access the route `admin/article/posts` it prompts me the login as expected. But after login it show null on `__construct()` method for `Auth::user()`;

I added `web` middleware as mentioned on [#204](https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules/issues/204) but it did not solve the issue. Can you please guide me to resolve this? My project is on Laravel 5.6 and using the latest version of Laravel-Modules

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Modules\Article\Http\Controllers\Backend', 'as' => 'backend.article.', 'middleware' => ['web', 'auth', 'can:view_backend'], 'prefix' => 'admin/article'], function () {

    Route::resource("posts", "PostsController");
});
```

My project is hosted at Github, https://github.com/nasirkhan/laravel-starter/tree/module

Answer (score 0):

First of all, add [Spatie Middleware](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission#using-a-middleware) to your kernel:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    // ...
    'role' => \Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\RoleMiddleware::class,
    'permission' => \Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\PermissionMiddleware::class,
];
```

Then in your  controller check for permission or roles:

```
public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->middleware(['permission: order.index']);
    }
```

Now you can access to your authenticated with $request->user() like:

```
public function create(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->user()->hasRole('admin')) {

           // return view("carmodel.create", ["manufacturers"=>$manufacturers]);
        } else {
            return view("admin.error", ['code'=>'001','msg'=>'err']);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs:

> In previous versions of Laravel, you could access session variables or the authenticated user in your controller's constructor. This was never intended to be an explicit feature of the framework. In Laravel 5.3, you can't access the session or authenticated user in your controller's constructor because the middleware has not run yet.
>
> As an alternative, you may define a Closure based middleware directly
>   in your controller's constructor. Before using this feature, make sure
>   that your application is running Laravel 5.3.4 or above:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        $this->projects = Auth::user()->projects;

        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

Or you could typehint it:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $projects = $request->user()->projects;

    $value = $request->session()->get('key');
}
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#5.3-session-in-constructors)